# Android Access to view model instance in properties

Tags: android, viewmodel

HomeFragment.tk :

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private val questionViewModel: QuestionListViewModel by viewModels {
    
    InjectorUtils.provideQuestionListViewModelFactory(this)
}

var allQuestionsCount :LiveData<Int>  = questionViewModel.getCountQuestions()
  
 ... ELSE CODE
}
```

If i use `questionViewModel` for initializing other properties(like the above code), get the error:

```
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:566)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-10-25 16:48:29.026 28597-28597/com.example.android.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
            ... 49 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{ad9f957} (58527bd1-4b47-493e-a080-0cc3920ea395)} not attached to a context.
```

But if instead i replace the `allQuestionsCount` property with :

```
lateinit var allQuestionsCount :LiveData<Int>
```

and then inside `onCreateView` initialize it:

```
 allQuestionsCount = questionViewModel.getCountQuestions()
```

now there is no error.I need to know whats wrong with the first approach?

Comment: Top-level variables are initialized before the constructor. Therefore, the fragment doesn't yet have a context, which I assume the injector requires to work.

Comment: @Zoe yes , the injector require the fragment instance.so you mean `viewmodel` is invoked by `allQuestionsCount` while it is not yes provided.is there any other method for initializing the `allQuestionsCount` property,or is it a proper way?

Comment: You can use `by lazy`, which means it won't be initialized until it's used, which should be after context creation provided you don't have anything else in the top-level or in a constructor that relies on the variable.

Comment: @Zoe I tested `by lazy` and assign value to view in `onCreateView` and it works.so the context is created in constructor and before `onCreateView` ?

Comment: It's created when the object is created, so technically before any of the lifecycle elements are triggered, I think. It's possible the context is created only when it's inflated (I honestly don't remember), but as long as you call stuff related to context in lifecycle steps, it should be fine.

Comment: @amin when you use `by lazy` property is created the first time when you use it and then the created value is used for next use cases. In other words when you use `by lazy` for a variable it will be created the first time you use variable and the created value is cached for next accesses to variable.